# ser.write() function in pyserial

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to send the byte array of an image file to the Arduino with the pyserial library. And I am receiving the data byte by byte in the Arduino. But it seems I am unable to retrieve the bytes on the Arduino. For example it sends a string of '255' Arduino receives the byte as '2'.

Python code:

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, bytesize=8, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)
f = open('image.jpg','rb')
l = f.read()
b = bytearray(l)
for i in range(1,len(b)):
  ser.write(str(b[i-1]))
ser.flush()
ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```cpp
char buffer ; // for incoming serial data
int length = 1;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  Serial.readBytes(&buffer, length) ;
  Serial.println(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Try in your `loop` function: `while(Serial.available() > 0) {  
    buffer = Serial.read(); 
    Serial.print(buffer);}`

Comment: In Python you are converting byte 255 to a string "255" and on Arduino side you are trying to print a non nul terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python code sends numbers as ASCII strings, instead of sending bytes (which is what your Arduino code is expecting...). Instead, do:

```
for i in range(1,len(b)):
  ser.write(b[i-1])
```